# Dual arm UR5 connection with universal robot stack

Tags: ros, follow-joint-trajectory, topic, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to setup a connection between PC and two UR5 arms , but the topic "follow joint tracjetory" cannot be created.The error displayed is "Action client not connected:left_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory" and "Action client not connected:right_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory" .
PS:I use the package "ur_modern_driver" and my ur5 version is CB3.0.

launch file in the "ur_bringup" package:

```
<launch>
 
 <group ns="left">
   <arg name="limited" default="false"/>
   <arg name="robot_ip" default="192.168.0.108"/>
   <arg name="reverse_port" default="50001"/>
   <arg name="min_payload"  default="0.0"/>
   <arg name="max_payload"  default="5.0"/>
   <arg name="prefix" default="left_" />
  <include file="$(find ur_bringup)/launch/ur5_left_bringup.launch">
   <arg name="limited" value="$(arg limited)"/>
   <arg name="robot_ip" value="$(arg robot_ip)"/>
   <arg name="reverse_port" value="$(arg reverse_port)"/>
   <arg name="min_payload"  value="$(arg min_payload)"/>
   <arg name="max_payload"  value="$(arg max_payload)"/>
   <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
  </include>
 </group>

 <group ns="right">
   <arg name="limited" default="false"/>
   <arg name="robot_ip" default="192.168.0.109"/>
   <arg name="reverse_port" default="50002"/>
   <arg name="min_payload"  default="0.0"/>
   <arg name="max_payload"  default="5.0"/>
   <arg name="prefix" default="right_" />
  <include file="$(find ur_bringup)/launch/ur5_right_bringup.launch">
   <arg name="limited" value="$(arg limited)"/>
   <arg name="robot_ip" value="$(arg robot_ip)"/>
   <arg name="reverse_port" value="$(arg reverse_port)"/>
   <arg name="min_payload"  value="$(arg min_payload)"/>
   <arg name="max_payload"  value="$(arg max_payload)"/>
   <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
  </include>
 </group>

</launch>
```

`controllers.yaml`:

```
controller_list:
  - name: right_arm_controller
    action_ns: right_follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - right_shoulder_pan_joint
      - right_shoulder_lift_joint
      - right_elbow_joint
      - right_wrist_1_joint
      - right_wrist_2_joint
      - right_wrist_3_joint

  - name: left_arm_controller
    action_ns: left_follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - left_shoulder_pan_joint
      - left_shoulder_lift_joint
      - left_elbow_joint
      - left_wrist_1_joint
      - left_wrist_2_joint
      - left_wrist_3_joint
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269074/dual-arm-ur5-connection-with-universal-robot-stack/) by [yyf](https://answers.ros.org/users/29997/yyf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-08-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In essence the "dual arm" aspect here is not important.

From the ROS perspective you're basically starting two instances of the same node, and need to use namespacing to avoid collisions.

From the 'error' you include it's not clear to me whether you have the namespacing configured correctly on the driver side, but if you did, then you would have to make sure that the action client config (probably MoveIt?) is aware of the namespaces / the correct topics.

You'll have to tell us more about your exact setup and configuration to be able to help you.

---

Edit:

> PS:I use the package "ur_modern_driver" and my ur5 version is CB3.0

and:

> launch file in the "ur_bringup" package:
>
> ...
>
> ```
>   <include file="$(find ur_bringup)/launch/ur5_left_bringup.launch">
> ```

Two things here:

1. if you're really using the `ur_bringup` package, then you're not using `ur_modern_driver`, but the old one `ur_driver`. You **cannot** use `ur_bringup` with `ur_modern_driver`.

   Use the launch files in [ur_modern_driver/launch](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/tree/master/launch).
2. what is in the `ur5_left_bringup.launch` and `ur5_right_bringup.launch` exactly? There should be no a need for custom launch files other than the one that `include`s the regular launch file twice, but in separate `ns`.

As to your `controllers.yaml`: the two instances of the driver are started in a `right` and a `left` namespace. I don't see that namespace anywhere in your `controllers.yaml`. The `action_ns` key should probably be something like `right/follow_joint_trajectory` (note the forward slash (`/`)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yyf](https://answers.ros.org/users/29997/yyf/) on 2017-08-18**:
thanks！I have added two files : **bring_up.launch** and **controller.yaml**. I tnink the problem is in the aspect of **ur_driver**

**Comment by [Soul Goumey](https://answers.ros.org/users/30230/soul-goumey/) on 2018-09-05**:
I solved the problem and now everything work as aspected. The problem was in my controllers.yaml because i didn't include the namespace name in the action_key. so i only added **ur5/**follow_joint_trajectory. thank you :)

**Comment by [zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/38380/zzz/) on 2018-11-05**:
@Soul Goumey  Hello! I have the same problem. I wonder to know how to add  the "action_key"? Did you modify the file "ur_ros_wrapper.cpp" in /ur_modern_driver/src/  ?

**Comment by [Soul Goumey](https://answers.ros.org/users/30230/soul-goumey/) on 2018-11-05**:
@zzz hello, you have the action key  in  urX_moveit_config/config/controllers.yaml
You don’t have to modify the ur-driver.cpp and the ros-wrapper

**Comment by [zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/38380/zzz/) on 2018-11-05**:
@Soul Goumey Thank you for your reply! Before this，I have tried modified the file “controllers.yaml” ，in which I added like this:

- name: "right_arm_controller"
  action_ns: ur5/follow_joint_trajectory
- name: "right_arm_controller"
  action_ns: right/follow_joint_trajectory

But,it failed

**Comment by [Soul Goumey](https://answers.ros.org/users/30230/soul-goumey/) on 2018-11-05**:
@zzz  can you then  give more details about what you are trying to do exactly( ros version, errors, Modifications you did...)

**Comment by [zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/38380/zzz/) on 2018-11-06**:
@Soul Goumey I can't paste my code here for the limit of a comment.I did the just the same code above like the questioner @yyf.Do you have meet the binding error ever before when using urX_bringup.launch for dual arms？When I cancel the section of the binding code, it's the action sever and ompl eror

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-06**:\

> Do you have meet the binding error ever before when using urX_bringup.launch for dual arms？

you need to make sure to set different values for the `reverse_port` arg of the two instances of the driver. Two processes cannot bind to the same TCP port.

**Comment by [zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/38380/zzz/) on 2018-11-06**:
I set them different IPs and ports in bringup and ur_common launch file ,whether the args have been  communicated into the ur_driver,I'm not sure...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-06**:
I would suggest to post a new question with all the pertinent details, as @Soul Goumey also asks.

Be sure to refer to this one and clarify that it's a follow-up.

**Comment by [zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/38380/zzz/) on 2018-11-06**:
https://answers.ros.org/question/307770/dual-arm-ur5-real-time-interconnection/
I added my code on this page.Thank you for help! @Soul Goumey  @gvdhoorn